# Name of the bill that congressmen should be subject to their own laws

Tags: united-states, congress

There was a proposal several years back that a law be passed that would prohibit congress from passing laws that congress would be exempt from. What was that called? I thought there was one that wasn't just employment law but also insider trading and libel laws.

Comment: When you get an answer which is correct but not what you expected because your question wasn't precise enough, you might want to consider writing a new question. See ["Question editing that invalidates answers"](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/question-editing-that-invalidates-answers) on meta.

Comment: @Philipp the answer is only partially correct. The answer provided is only true for employment law

Comment: Were you thinking of the Constitutional Amendment introduced by Ron DeSantis (FL-06)?

Comment: I agree a constitutional amendment, which is not a law but a joint resolution by 2/3 vote of Congress, is a compelling answer. It would be the 28th and has been proposed by various sources. There is a legitimate concern that applying laws to Congress may run afoul of separation of powers concerning the judiciary interfering with the legislative branch; an amendment is the thing that can fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may mean the * Congress Leads By Example Act of 2011 * bill introduced by Congresswoman Eleanor Holmes Norton, and reintroduced in 2013. [Norton Press Release](https://norton.house.gov/media-center/press-releases/norton-introduces-bill-to-bring-congress-under-workplace-rights-laws)

Comment: That's helpful but do you know the one that covered insider trading etc.

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot Stop Trading On Congressional Knowledge, STOCK, Act, though that isn't what your question asks for.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I thought there was a generalized version